# Uninitialized string offset php

Tags: php, string, initialization, offset, notice

I am writting my own calculator on PHP.

I have a problem with my code because i don't know where i am trying to read too far in the string. So if anyone can enlighten me ..

The exact error i get is :

> PHP Notice:  Uninitialized string offset: 4 in /home/salim/Bureau/web/piscine_php/d01/ex11/do_op_2.php on line 76

Here is the code below :

```
function decoupe ($argv)
{
global $nbr1;
global $nbr2;
global $sign;
$string = NULL;
$string = trim($argv[1], " \t");
echo $string;
echo "\n";
$x = 0;
while($string[$x]) 
{
    if (is_numeric($string[0]) == false)
        error_msg();
    if (is_numeric($string[$x]) && $string[$x + 1])
    {
        while (is_numeric($string[$x]))
        {
            $nbr1 .= $string[$x];
            $x++;
        }
    }
    if (is_thisoperator(substr($string, $x)))
    {
        $sign .= $string[$x];
        $x++;
    }
    else
    {
        error_msg();
    }

    if ($string[$x + 1] && is_numeric($string[$x]))
    {
        while (is_numeric($string[$x]))
        {
            $nbr2 .= $string[$x];
            $x++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        error_msg();
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line is getting the error?

Comment: it appears this one :    if ($string[$x + 1] && is_numeric($string[$x]))

Comment: If you want to make a usable arithmetic evaluator while only pulling out a minimal amount of hair, you're going to want to get friendly with the [Shunting-Yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `$string[$x]` as a way to test whether `$x` is a valid index in the string. It prints a warning when `$x` is outside the string. Use `$x < strlen($string)` instead. So change:

```
while ($string[$x])
```

to

```
while ($x < strlen($string))
```

and change

```
if ($string[$x + 1] && is_numeric($string[$x]))
```

to

```
if ($x + 1 < strlen($string) && is_numeric($string[$x]))
```

Comment: Thank's you very much for your answer :) But i would like to know is there a difference in this way between C language and PHP one , because in C i code like that and i don't really meet problem until know ..

Comment: In C, there's a null character at the end of the string, and that's what that type of test is looking for. PHP doesn't have that.